# Cannot open powerpoint addin csproj file in vs2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, add-in, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint addin project which was created in VisualStudio 2010 - I upgraded to vs2012 and am getting errors when opening it

```
W:\path\to\PPTAddIn.csproj : error  : The project file 'W:\path\to\PPTAddIn.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.
```

I can't find any documentation on this issue. Anyone know what's going on and how to fix it.